# Failable initializer in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a custom UITableViewCel (nothing fancy) that works perfectly on Xcode 6.0.
When I try to compile it with Xcode 6.1 the compiler shows the following error:

`A non-failable initializer cannot chain to failable initializer 'init(style:reuseIdentifier:)' written with 'init?'`

Here is the code of the cell:

```
class MainTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.setup()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
    }

    func setup() {<...>}
}
```

As a solution the compiler proposes `Propagate the failure with 'init?'`:

```
override init?(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.setup()
}
```

I'm a bit confused. 
Is it possible to elaborate what is a `(non)failable initialiser` and how it should be used and overrided?

Comment: You are problaby speaking of Xcode 6.0 and 6.1 ?

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's almost a night where I am and I'm a bit sleepy. :)

Comment: Also, as I understand it, you should be putting the super.init call at the bottom of the function. I guess if you don't have any properties, then it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With Swift 1.1 (in Xcode 6.1) Apple introduced *failable initializers* -- that is, initializers that can return `nil` instead of an instance. You define a failable initializer by putting a `?` after the `init`. The initializer you're trying to override changed its signature between Xcode 6.0 and 6.1:

```
// Xcode 6.0
init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)

// Xcode 6.1
init?(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
```

So to override you'll need to make the same change to your initializer, and make sure to handle the `nil` case (by assigning to an optional) when creating a cell that way.

You can read more about [failable initializers in Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_339).

Comment: How would you recommend to handle the nil case?